# Which Linux kernel modules are related to heat, fan speed, and power management

Tags: linux, power-management, fan, cooling, kernel-module

Which Linux kernel modules are related to fan speed, temperature monitoring and power management.  The goal of my question is to provide a starting point for understanding which Linux kernel modules will help a laptop better perform in regards to power management when on battery, as well as heat management to prevent overheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/) is the standard module for monitoring hardware components.

There are kernel modules that use ACPI for power management but I think the pm-utils package has become the more common way to control it.